# How to get this prompts module to prompt more than once?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Comparing the same code with two different npm modules.
A) [promt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt), where for each turn prompt asks player to enter number and it works like expected.
and
B) [promts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompts), asks only first time to enter number, then just loops players with the same provided number without prompting to enter other values. What is missing or wrong here?

A) sample code:

```
import * as prompt from "prompt";
import * as chalk from "chalk";

var board = {
  1: "·",
  2: "·",
  3: "·",
  4: "·",
  5: "·",
  6: "·",
  7: "·",
  8: "·",
  9: "·",
};

/////////function to print position and marks //////////////
function makeBoard(position, mark) {
  board[position] = mark;
}

////////////function to print to console/////////
function printBoard() {
  console.log(
    chalk.green.bold(
      "\n" +
        "                              " +
        board[1] +
        " | " +
        board[2] +
        " | " +
        board[3] +
        "\n" +
        "                              ---------\n" +
        "                              " +
        board[4] +
        " | " +
        board[5] +
        " | " +
        board[6] +
        "\n" +
        "                              ---------\n" +
        "                              " +
        board[7] +
        " | " +
        board[8] +
        " | " +
        board[9] +
        "\n"
    )
  );
}

function playerTurn(player) {
  prompt.start();
  prompt.get(["position"], function(err, result) {
    console.log("Your turn player: ", player);
    makeBoard(result.position, player);
    printBoard();
    if (player === "X") {
      playerTurn("O");
    } else {
      playerTurn("X");
    }
  });
}
playerTurn("X");
```

Result is as expected:

[image]

B) sample code:

```
import * as prompts from "prompts";
import * as chalk from "chalk";

interface Coordinates {
  value: number;
}

var board = {
  1: "·",
  2: "·",
  3: "·",
  4: "·",
  5: "·",
  6: "·",
  7: "·",
  8: "·",
  9: "·",
};
(async () => {
  console.clear();
  /////////function to print position and marks //////////////
  function makeBoard(position, mark) {
    board[position] = mark;
  }

  ////////////function to print to console/////////
  function printBoard() {
    console.log(
      chalk.green.bold(
        "\n" +
          "                              " +
          board[1] +
          " | " +
          board[2] +
          " | " +
          board[3] +
          "\n" +
          "                              ---------\n" +
          "                              " +
          board[4] +
          " | " +
          board[5] +
          " | " +
          board[6] +
          "\n" +
          "                              ---------\n" +
          "                              " +
          board[7] +
          " | " +
          board[8] +
          " | " +
          board[9] +
          "\n"
      )
    );
  }

  const response = await prompts([
    {
      type: "number",
      name: "value",
      message: "Enter number from 1-9:",
      validate: (value) =>
        value > 0 && value < 10 && board[value] === "·"
          ? true
          : `Enter number from 1-9`,
    },
  ]);

  function playerTurn(player) {
    console.log("Your turn player: ", player);
    makeBoard(response.value, player);
    printBoard();
    if (player === "X") {
      playerTurn("O");
    } else {
      playerTurn("X");
    }
  }
  playerTurn("X");
})();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense for me. In the second code you are calling `const response = await prompts(` once. Why do you expect something to happen multiple times? In the first code you are calling `prompt.get(["position"], function(err, result) {` in a recursive function.

Comment: You could use your debugger to step line by line through the code to see why the codes behave differently.